# Help with identifying varistor

Tags: identification, varistor

[image]

I need help with identifying this varistor. I hhave Been trying to figure it out since 5 pm yesterday. I cannot find anything about it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bump. I could really use the help, guys.

Comment: I'm merely a hobbyist and no professional. But I would have guessed that the "103" would mean 10nF (which can apply to varistors); that although the 560-2 VDE spec can apply either to caps or to varistors, the 5U suggests Y5U (may be consistent with 10nF); and so I'm leaning towards "capacitor." Are you sure it's a varistor? For example, see this from [Panasonic ceramic disc caps](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/103697.pdf).

Comment: I have no idea between the two. But either way, I need to find what company it is from. Not so worried about replacing at the moment or specs. Just need to know who manufactures them.

Comment: Does it still work? Are there any current indications on the silkscreen?

Comment: Funny though that all the other Matsushita varistors I find are ZNR line, none of them are from this NS line.

Comment: In fact, from the nomenclature in this document, it is probably a NS ceramic capacitor with 10 nF (as previously mentioned) https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/315/abb0000ce11-292412.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a part from Matsushita, which would now be Panasonic.

[image: manufacturer marking]

I found a few parts with that logo and Matsushita mentioned, but can't find a real source for that.

@jonk mentioned that it is likely a capacitor and not a varistor.

There is a [NS-A line of capacitors](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/315/abb0000ce11-292412.pdf) offered by Panasonic, which could be the successor for the NS you have there.

Comment: Anyone know where I can find a possible replacement then?